# Combining DEM, GeoTiff and CityGML in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, citygml

I'm trying to combine DEM, GeoTiff, and CityGML in QGIS to create a 3D representation like in [this example](https://www.3dcitydb.org/3dcitydb/visualizationberlin/).

The problem I have is that:-

1. The CityGML buildings are hovering above the 3D view and
2. The GeoTiff doesn't take the shape of the CityGML buildings like it does with the DEM. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I'm working with [open data](https://www.geodaten.sachsen.de/digitale-hoehenmodelle-3994.html). They offer the LoD2 data in the CityGML, DXF, and Shape format. In QGIS the CityGML buildings are just displayed as 2D contour lines, whereas the DXF and Shapefiles are properly displayed as 3D. Is the data corrupted? For reference here is the data I used:
[DEM](https://geocloud.landesvermessung.sachsen.de/index.php/s/TaMITVMms2Bvkic/download?path=%2F&&files=dgm1_4125656.zip), [CityGML](https://geocloud.landesvermessung.sachsen.de/index.php/s/1RwW5XNaGctSRM2/download?path=%2F&&files=3D_LoD2_CityGML_33412_5656_2_sn.zip), [DXF](https://geocloud.landesvermessung.sachsen.de/index.php/s/5AZDJpn2OZJekWr/download?path=%2F&&files=3D_LoD2_DXF_33412_5656_2_sn.zip), [Shape](https://geocloud.landesvermessung.sachsen.de/index.php/s/jYFF83aybL0OPxO/download?path=%2F&&files=3D_LoD2_Shape_33412_5656_2_sn.zip), [GeoTiff](https://geocloud.landesvermessung.sachsen.de/index.php/s/qibG253ZRoYsmO8/download?path=%2F&&files=dop20c_4125656.zip)

Comment: what coordinate reference systems are used by the various datasets?

Comment: All use EPSG:25833 - ETRS89